# Change plot window size in IPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using IPython Notebook to make some plots. For most of them I use 
`%matplotlib inline` but for a few I change to `%matplotlib notebook` to be able to zoom in and stuff like that.

Now to the problem, the window displaying my plot (independent of what matplotlib setting I am using) suddenly became much smaller. Not the figure itself, just the window. I am really confused why this happened, if it was beacause I was switching between the two matplotlib settings or something else I made by mistake.

It is really annoying since I have to scroll in the window to se my whole figure unless I want to minimize it a lot. So if you have any idea how to make the plot window larger, please enlighten me.

Here you can se an example of what I mean by window: [Small window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gnwI.png). The 'window' according to me is where you can see "Figure 1" and the red button and ends where it cuts my plot.

Comment: can you post an example notebook to a gist or something?  or a screenshot?  By window you mean the browser window?

Comment: Ok, I posted a screenshot to make it more clear.

Comment: Click on the space to the left of the figure to in fold the scroll area

Answer (score 23):

Click to expand fully and show smaller.  Double click to completely collapse it.

[image: Expand Jupyter notebook matplotlib inline window by clicking to left]

Comment: Any idea how to make charts show fully expanded by default?

Comment: It seems the status is saved in the notebook.  If you expand and save, next time it is expanded from the start.